# how to best make a static method for an object variable

Tags: java, static, static-methods

i have two java classes, one is called MultiThreader, and the other is ConnectionUtility, wanted to create a static function so i can set text to a textfield anywhere in either of the two classes, accessing the textField from the ConnectionUtility class is easy, just using the .setText("textToShow")

however using the method from the other class i have to instantiate a ConnectionUtility object each time i use the static method, this sounds like a waste of resources as object creation in Android or Java is expensive. is there a better way to do this than the example shown here?  and is this example a bad use of resources?

```
public static void printOutText(String string){
    ConnectionUtility cu = new ConnectionUtility();
    cu.jTextField1.setText(string);
    cu = null;
}
```

EDIT: part of the situation for the question is that i want to avoid making the jTextField1 object static.  for this condition it would be class member variable only

EDIT TWO:  I FORGOT TO MENTION, this is for a Java desktop app, not Android app.   MY MISTAKE for not making that clear.  i am more used to Android, have not done much in Java JFrame before.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html use application class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some discussion about [whether to avoid object creation in Java or not](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149563/should-we-avoid-object-creation-in-java). I think, especially in a desktop environment, you shouldn't be too worried about instantiating objects. After all, your working with an object-oriented programming language. What use would that be if you reduced everything to static implementations? This would result in writing procedural code in an oo language!

In most cases performance issues really come from bad choices of algorithms, not from using native language features. If you're really facing performance issues on that level, you should think about switching to C/C++ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use handlers and message passing for that. there's a good example here:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html